# UIActivityViewController showing body text in subject at gmail and yahoo mail not showing subject swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

```
func mail_Compose(tag:Int)
{
    let dict = arrFilter?[tag] as? [String: AnyObject]
    let jobTitle = dict?["job_title"] as? String
    let cmpName = dict?["emo_company_name"] as? String
    let customUrl = dict?["custom_url"] as? String
  //  var url = ""
    let title = "Job opening for " + jobTitle!
    let content = "Job opening for \(jobTitle!) at \(cmpName!)\n"

    //Handle nil value
    guard let name = customUrl else {
        alert(message: "Url not found")
        return
    }

    let objectsToShare:Any?

    if let myWebsite = URL(string:  webServiceMailUrl + name) {
        objectsToShare = [content,myWebsite] as [Any]
    } else {
        objectsToShare = [content] as [Any]
    }

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare as! [Any], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.setValue(title, forKey: "Subject")
    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .pad {
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: CGFloat(view.bounds.size.width / 2), y: CGFloat(view.bounds.size.height / 4), width: CGFloat(0), height: CGFloat(0))
    }
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [.print, .postToWeibo, .copyToPasteboard, .addToReadingList, .postToVimeo]

    present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

- Working perfect in mail client but not working in gmail and yahoo mail.
- [Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1YTQ.jpg)
- [Yahoo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2br6l.jpg)
- [Mail client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO0eQ.jpg) - Need like this format in google and yahoo.
- I tried many ways but not get any solution. Someone helps how to solve this issue.
- Please find the above links gmail,yahoo and mail client.

Comment: This seems to be a issue from Gmail, and has been there for 2-3 years.

Comment: If there is any solution for now?

Comment: Not that i know off. Sorry!

Comment: Did anyone found solution for this?